# What framework to use for touch input tracking for Windows Store app using C#, XAML

Tags: c#, xaml, visual-studio-2012, windows-store-apps

I am using C# with XAML in Visual Studio 2012, and programming a "Windows Store" app. I am looking for the right framework to capture and track touch inputs. In particular, when a user draws lines on the screen, I am looking to track those trajectories, by capturing the position of the user's finger over time. For example, find the (x,y) location every half second or so. I would also need to find out when a user does the "touch down" event and when the user the "touch up" event.

I don't need multi-touch in this case.

Which framework should I be using to achieve these requirements?

Thanks.

Comment: You are already using C# and XAML, what do you mean by framework? pls clarify. Also did you check this? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465387.aspx

Answer (score 1):

You can use Pointer Events, that support both mouse and touch

```
PointerPressed and PointerReleased Events
```

You can check more here :
[Quick Start: Touch Inputs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465387#using_manipulation_events)